# circular infinite scrollview in objective c

Tags: uiscrollview

I have added a button in a uiscrollview and 5 buttons visible in scrollview at a time. I want to make a circular effect in uiscrollview without paging following functionality are needed.

1. Circular scrolling for example: 5 1 2 3 4 5 1
2. Make a selection in uiscrollview like uipickerview when any button selected in scrollview. Then it goes in center:

   For example--before selection: 1 2 3 4 5, when suppose select 5th button, then after selection: 3 4 5 1 2. 
   And when select left button from center the move the scrollview right, when right btn then move the scrollview left.
3. Suppose O scroll the scrollview when select button in mid of scrolling, then button event is not fired.